# How to chain functions with underscore js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

New to underscore.  Trying to clean up my code by chaining things together.

tried this but no success:

```
keys = _(arrayofobjects).first().keys()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at the chain function

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `_.chain()` and `.value()` to use the chaining functions:

```
keys = _.chain(arrayofobjects).first().keys().value()
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#chaining